# Getting FB Token Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, robobrowser

I'm trying to get FB token to Tinder, but i'm stuck in some errors after submit the CONFIRM form. I`ve tried to pass the exception, but still fails.

```py
import re
import robobrowser
import sys
import  random
import time

MOBILE_USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_5 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15D60 AKiOSSDK/4.29.0'

FB_AUTH = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fb464891386855067%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=user_birthday%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_education_history%2Cemail%2Cuser_relationship_details%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_likes&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&client_id=464891386855067&ret=login&fallback_redirect_uri=221e1158-f2e9-1452-1a05-8983f99f7d6e&ext=1556057433&hash=Aea6jWwMP_tDMQ9y'

def get_access_token(email, password):
    s = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(user_agent=MOBILE_USER_AGENT, parser="lxml")
    s.open(FB_AUTH)
    ## submit login form
    f = s.get_form()
    f["pass"] = password
    f["email"] = email
    s.submit_form(f)

    ## click the 'ok' button on the dialog informing you that you have already authenticated with the Tinder app
    f = s.get_form()
    time.sleep(random.random()*1.5)
    s.submit_form(f, submit=f.submit_fields['__CONFIRM__'])

    ## get access token from the http response
    access_token = re.search(r"access_token=([\w\d]+)", s.response.content.decode()).groups()[0]
    return access_token



email = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
access_token = get_access_token(email, password)

print(access_token)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TokenRefresh.py", line 33, in <module>
    access_token = get_access_token(email, password)
  File "TokenRefresh.py", line 23, in get_access_token
    s.submit_form(f, submit=f.submit_fields['__CONFIRM__'])
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\robobrowser\browser.py", line 343, in submit_form
    response = self.session.request(method, url, **send_args)
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 668, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 668, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 247, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 640, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "C:\Users\silva\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 731, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for '%s'" % url)
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for... '
```

I can get the response, but the code still fails to return the access_token.

Answer (score 0):

How about this `res = browser.submit_form(form, submit='__CONFIRM__')`

Comment: Submits needs a name. `if submit not in submit_fields.getlist(submit.name):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name' `

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more research, I`ve found the solution.

```
import re
import robobrowser
import sys
import  random
import time

MOBILE_USER_AGENT = "Tinder/7.5.3 (iPhone; iOS 10.3.2; Scale/2.00)"

FB_AUTH = 'https://www.facebook.com/v2.6/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fb464891386855067%3A%2F%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=user_birthday%2Cuser_photos%2Cuser_education_history%2Cemail%2Cuser_relationship_details%2Cuser_friends%2Cuser_work_history%2Cuser_likes&response_type=token%2Csigned_request&client_id=464891386855067&ret=login&fallback_redirect_uri=221e1158-f2e9-1452-1a05-8983f99f7d6e&ext=1556057433&hash=Aea6jWwMP_tDMQ9y'

def get_access_token(email, password):
    s = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(user_agent=MOBILE_USER_AGENT, parser="lxml")
    s.open(FB_AUTH)
    ## submit login form
    f = s.get_form()
    f["pass"] = password
    f["email"] = email
    s.submit_form(f)

    ## click the 'ok' button on the dialog informing you that you have already authenticated with the Tinder app
    f = s.get_form()
    try:
        s.submit_form(f, submit=f.submit_fields['__CONFIRM__'])
        #print(s.response.content.decode())
        access_token = re.search(
            r"access_token=([\w\d]+)", s.response.content.decode()).groups()[0]
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema as browserAddress:
        #print(type(browserAddress))
        #print(str(browserAddress))
        access_token = re.search(
             r"access_token=([\w\d]+)", str(browserAddress)).groups()[0]
        return(access_token)



email = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]
access_token = get_access_token(email, password)
```